# Tracking users' posts

Tags: django, django-models

How is it better to implement the following task:

There are users, users can create posts.
It is necessary to make it possible to subscribe to users, to see the messages of those you subscribed to (as in the livejournal).
How is it better to implement it? What are the best relationships in the model?

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a many-to-many relationship. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships

```
User(models.Model):
   …
   subscribers = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

Comment: The question, as written, is very broad - it's just a requirement (e.g. it looks like a homework/classroom assignment), with no code or other effort shown. Best not to answer someone's assignment when they don't show any work. Also, there is more than one relationship being described, and you're making a broadstroke statement that they are all many-to-many, which doesn't seem like the case.

Comment: How do you know its a homework assignment? Are you a mind reader? And three lines of code in my answer can hardly be considered doing the work for the original poster.

Comment: You're right - it could be a challenge from a book, or even some idea the OP dreamed up. But there's no specific programming question, and it's very broad with no objective answer. If you look at the help center, you'll see that this type of question is off-topic, as I already mentioned.

Comment: Yes there is a specific programming question. `What are the best relationships in the model?` That is specific to Django and Django models. It is clear that English is not the posters native language and they may not be able to express themselves to some people's satisfaction, but that didn't bother me. Be nice :)